# Can I find out the allocation request that caused my Python MemoryError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, out-of-memory

#### Context

My small Python script uses a library to work on some relatively large data. The standard algorithm for this task is a dynamic programming algorithm, so presumably the library "under the hood" allocates a large array to keep track of the partial results of the DP. Indeed, when I try to give it fairly large input, it immediately gives a `MemoryError`.

Preferably without digging into the depths of the library, I want to figure out if it is worth trying this algorithm on a different machine with more memory, or trying to trim down a bit on my input size, or if it's a lost cause for the data size I am trying to use.

#### Question

When my Python code throws a `MemoryError`, is there a "top-down" way for me to investigate what the size of memory was that my code tried to allocate which caused the error, e.g. by inspecting the error object?

Comment: This is a good overview on MemoryError: https://airbrake.io/blog/python-exception-handling/memoryerror . What is the DP library you're using? What is the size of the very large input? Similar to the forced out of bounds in the blog post, you could try looping through and allocating memory based on N and throwing it away until it fails. That'll tell you where N breaks down. As for your direct question, " how to investigate what the size of memory was that my code tried to allocate which caused the error," I did not see anything immediately obvious. Interesting question!

Comment: @ScottSkiles, at this point my practical problem has more or less been solved with an approximate/probabilistic solution, and it's just a curiosity for me about error objects in Python. The context is just to make clear why one might care about the problem, and mostly separate from the actual question. The algorithm was for computing a variant of Levenshtein distance for approximate substring matching, and my data was (if I recall correctly) around a million characters.

Comment: From the article referenced by @ScottSkiles, it seems like you could use [`psutil.virtual_memory()`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory) in your error handling to get the memory usage data you are looking for. That said, I am not aware of a way to get this info from the error itself per your question.

Comment: @ScottSkiles @benvc if either of you would turn the fact about `psutil` into an answer I'd be happy to accept and award bounty.

Comment: @benvc go ahead. I'm traveling.

Comment: It might not be useful after the fact, and doesn't use the error object, but I often use [objgraph](https://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) to determine if something is creating a large number of objects and how much memory they are consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't see from the `MemoryError` exception, and the exception is raised for *any* situation where memory allocation failed, including Python internals that do not directly connect to code creating new Python data structures; some modules create locks or other support objects and those operations can fail due to memory having run out.

You also can't necessarily know how much memory would be required to have the whole operation succeed. If the library creates several data structures over the course of operation, trying to allocate memory for a string used as a dictionary key could be the last straw, or it could be copying the whole existing data structure for mutation, or anything in between, but this doesn't say anything about how much memory is going to be needed, in addition, for the remainder of the process.

That said, Python can give you detailed information on what memory allocations are being made, and when, and where, using the [`tracemalloc` module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tracemalloc.html#module-tracemalloc). Using that module and an experimental approach, you could estimate how much memory your data set would require to complete.

The trick is to find data sets for which the process **can** be completed. You'd want to find data sets of different sizes, and you can then measure how much memory *those* data structures require. You'd create snapshots before and after with [`tracemalloc.take_snapshot()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tracemalloc.html#tracemalloc.take_snapshot), compare differences and [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tracemalloc.html#tracemalloc.Snapshot.statistics) between the snapshots for those data sets, and perhaps you can extrapolate from that information how much more memory your larger data set would need. It depends, of course, on the nature of the operation and the datasets, but if there is any kind of pattern `tracemalloc` is your best shot to discover it.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the memory allocation with [Pyampler](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/) but you will need to add the debugging statements locally in the library that you are using. Assuming a standard PyPi package, here are the steps:

1. Clone the package locally.

2 Use [summary module](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/muppy.html#the-summary-module) of Pyampler. Place following inside the main recursion method,

```
   from pympler import summary
   def data_intensive_method(data_xyz)
       sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
       summary.print_(sum1)
       ...
```

3. Run `pip install -e .` to install the edited package locally.
4. Run your main program and check the console for memory usage at each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `MemoryError` is not created with any associated data:

```
def crash():
    x = 32 * 10 ** 9
    return 'a' * x

try:
    crash()
except MemoryError as e:
    print(vars(e))  # prints: {}
```

This makes sense - how could it if no memory is left?

I don't think there's an easy way out. You can start from the traceback that the `MemoryError` causes and investigate with a debugger or use a memory profiler like [pympler](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/) (or psutil as suggested in the comments).